# Clean URL pagination (rewrite ?page=parameter)

Tags: 8, paging

One of my client works with an SEO agency and they ask me to remove the pagination parameter `?page=x` (generated by the Views module) and rewrite it like this:

Before:

```
/my-page?page=1
```

After:

```
/my-page-1
```

Is there a way to do it with Drupal? I don't see any option in the view or in Pathauto to do this.

Is it possible to handle this with a custom module or should I work with `.htaccess` file?

I've tried the [Clean Pagination](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleanpager) module but you have to manually set pages where clean pagination should work and the module doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: The usual evidence-free "advice" from SEO agencies, I note. There are potential issues with paginated lists and SEO but doing this won't solve them. Here's a more useful article. https://www.hallaminternet.com/avoiding-the-seo-pitfalls-of-url-parameters/

Answer (score 4):

You should write a PathProcessor that implements:

- `Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface`
- `Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface`

Example:

file: modules/custom/mymodule/src/PathProcessor/MymodulePathProcessor.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor;

use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;

class MymodulePathProcessor implements InboundPathProcessorInterface, OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    if (strpos($path, '/my-page-') !== 0) {
       return $path;
    }
    $page =  preg_replace("/^\/my-page-(\d+)/", '$1', $path);
      if (ctype_digit($page)) {
        \Drupal::request()->query->set('page', $page);
        return "/my-page";
    }
    else {
      \Drupal::request()->query->set('page', 0);
      return "/my-page";
    }
    return $path;
  }

  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = [], Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    if ($path === '/my-page' && isset($options['query']['page'])) {
      $page = $options['query']['page'];
      unset($options['query']['page']);
      return '/my-page-' . $page;
    }
    return $path;
  }

}
```

file: modules/custom/mymodule/mymodule.services.yml

```
services:
  mymodule.path_processor:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor\MymodulePathProcessor
    tags:
    - { name: path_processor_outbound}
    - { name: path_processor_inbound}
```

We also need to do a custom alteration to the pager. For the full pager the links are not created as the usual *link render elements*, so they don't go through the `processOutboud`, instead the twig file (classy/templates/navigation/pager.html.twig) uses a custom format. The next hook function does the adjustment.

file: modules/custom/mymodule/mymodule.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 * Implements hook_preprocess_pager().
 *
 * @param $variables
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_pager(&$variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  if ($current_path === '/my-page')
  foreach ($variables['items']['pages'] as &$page_link) {
    $page =  preg_replace("/^\?page=(\d+)/", '$1', $page_link['href']);
    $page_link['href'] = 'my-page-' . $page;
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your answer was upvoted multiple times, I guess the solution is here. But when I try it, I have this error : `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /my-page" in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest()` Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I just updated the code, turns out you can't just pass the `page` parameter in the $path. You have to add it to the `Request` object like this: `\Drupal::request()->query->set('page', $page);`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to study this question. Did you test your module or is it untested code ? I’ve tested it, I have no more `No route found` error but it doesn’t rewrite the url. If it is working for you, I’m doing something wrong, that’s why I ask.

Comment: You are welcome! I did test it...

Comment: Finally, I've noticed that the module is working with `Views Mini Pager` but not with  `Paged output, full pager`. Is it the same for you ? With `Views Mini Pager`, the url is rewritten, ie `/my-page-1` but the parameter is still here, ie` /my-page-1?page=1` Is it the same for you ?

Comment: I just corrected the `processOutbound`, with `unset($options['query']['page']);`... My bad, I hadn't noticed the page parameter was still being rendered in the pager.

Comment: I've noticed that adding `unset($options['query']['page']);` break the pager. The content are no more paginated. Do you also see the issue ?

Comment: It is easier to see the changes in the _edited 1 hour ago_ link at the bottom. I actually changed 3 lines of code:  `$page = $options['query']['page']`; `unset($options['query']['page'])`; `return '/my-page-' . $page`;

Comment: Link _[edited 1 hour ago](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/268482/revisions)_

Comment: I just added the fix for the full pager and the explanation: 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/268482/revisions

Comment: @SébastienGicquel, did you ever get to test the last version? in case it worked would you please mark it as the answer

Comment: Yes, I’ve tested your updated code but I still have some issue (I test it on a clean new Drupal 8 install). For testing, I create a `View` that list content type article and set pagination. The URL are rewritten but content is not updated and there are issue with next/prev button. Be sure ì will mark your answer as correct when I will be able to make it work.

Comment: I've tried this today with D10. The URL's are updated in the pager. However clicking on them redirects back the the first page.